# Forcibly discarding Python Imaging Library images to reclaim memory

Tags: python, memory, python-imaging-library

I have a program that loads and processes lots of images, of this form:

```
for fn in filenames:
    im = Image.open(fn)
    get_some_basic_stats(im)
```

When run on many images the Python process ends up using large amounts of memory -- far more than any one image should account for.  Needless to say this eventually results in thrashing the page file.

I assume (though I'm not 100% sure, obviously) it's because previous images are occupying memory until they are garbage collected.

Is there a way to forcibly discard them?  I was unable to find one in the [PIL reference](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm).  I thought of using `del im` but I understood this would simply remove the name 'im' from the local scope, and effectively be the same as reassigning it at the top of the loop.

Comment: As a side note: you might wish to check the [`weakref` module](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html). It is not an answer to your question directly, but using it might allow you to bypass certain code behaviours that are otherwise unavoidable.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in python can explicitly destroyed. In CPython, everything is reference counted so it should be deallocated as soon as nothing references it. In your case that should be happening in the next iteration of the loop. You can force the cyclical garbage collector by running `gc.collect()` but I doubt that'll solve the problem here.

You could try:
`print sys.getrefcount(im)` at the end of the loop. It'll tell you how many objects reference the image. It should be 2 (one for the local variable, one for im as a parameter to getrefcount). If its larger then that explains why the object isn't being deallocated.

You can also look at `gc.getobjects()` which will return a list of all the objects in the python system. I'd write a quick loop that counts up the object of different types and prints them. See if the count is going up on anything.

Comment: It's true nothing in Python can be destroy; but it isn't necessarily true of external modules such as PIL. ;-)  The idea of printing out the counts for each type sounds excellent, so I'm trying that first.

Comment: @Edmund, true, external modules can provide whatever API they like. I'm unaware of any that support deallocating objects. (Other resources like sockets/files/etc yes, but memory, no.)